# Segmentation fault in my Vigenere encryption program

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I'm new to programming. This is the code as I've written it so far. Disregard the details of the encryption itself; I know that will need more work. When I try to run the program, I get a segmentation fault error message. If `argc != 2` I will get the message and if `argc == 2` it prints out "keyword" but then it shows the same message and doesn't complete the program, so I think the error has something to do with referincing argv[1].

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
   int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]);
   char KeyWord[i]; 

    //makes sure command line has 2 arguements
    if (2 != argc) 

        printf("argc != 2. Try again\n");
        return 1;


    //stores argv[1] as key
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        KeyWord[i] = argv[1][i];  //malloc
        printf("%c", KeyWord[i]);
    }
   printf("\n");

    if (isalpha(KeyWord))
        return 0;
    else
     {   
        printf("try again");
        return 1;
     }

      int j, length;

     printf("input data: ");
     string message = GetString();

     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)   
     {  
        for (j = 0, length = strlen(message); j < length; j++)
        {
            if (islower(message[j]))
            message[j] = message[j] -97 + KeyWord[i];

            if (isupper(message[j]))
            message[j] = message[j] -65 + KeyWord[i];
        }  
        if (i==n) i = 0;
      }  
}
```

Comment: `string argv[]` what's this?

Comment: `<cs50.h>` provides `typedef char *string;` —— that's what `string argv[]` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compute `strlen(argv[1])` in the initialization of `n` before making sure that `argc == 2`.

Also, `char KeyWord[i]` is wrong: since `i` is 0, you are not allocating space for anything. This should at least yield a warning when you compile it, since array sizes must be greater than 0. If you want dynamic allocation, which your comment suggests, you should use `malloc` after computing the string's length.

The code should be:

```
int i = 0, n;
char *KeyWord; 

// make sure command line has 2 arguments
if (2 != argc) 
{
    printf("argc != 2. Try again\n");
    return 1;
}
n = strlen(argv[1]);
KeyWord = malloc(n+1);
/* ... */
```